# OxyPlot - выноска на графике

Tags: graphics, oxyplot

Здравствуйте. Можно ли в OxyPlot отобразить выноску/подпись в точке. Пример на картинке. Выноски - это зелёные квадратики прикреплённые к некоторой точке на графике.
[image: Пример графика с выноской]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можно. То, что вы называете выноской в `OxyPlot` называется [Annotations (аннотация)](http://docs.oxyplot.org/en/latest/models/annotations/index.html)

В OxyPlot доступны несколько видов аннотаций, таких как

- `ArrowAnnotation` (в виде стрелки)
- `PointAnnotation` (в виде точки)
- `TextAnnotation` (обычная надпись)
- `RectangleAnnotation`(в виде прямоугольника)

и многие другие, смотрите в документации или в исходниках библиотеки.

Такой аннотации как у вас на картике там нет (во всяком случае не нашел).

Если вам нужна собственная аннотация вы можете или комбинировать уже существующие или реализовать свой тип унаследовавшись от абстрактного базового класса для аннотаций с соответствующим названием - [Annotation](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/develop/Source/OxyPlot/Annotations/Annotation.cs)